# CardboardView opentok stereo renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opentok, google-cardboard

I'm testing out OpenTok for use in a VR app we are building. Using the opentok android SDK samples as a staring point I have modified the CustomVideoRenderer class to support CardboardView and corresponding StereoRenderer interface instead of GLSurfaceView and its Render interface.  The switch between CardboardView and GLSurfaceView is almost trivial and works fine in other cases (eg in other apps that do not use opentok).  In this case it didn't work at all and only after some tinkering with shaders and texture setup properties I was actually able to get anything to appear on the screen! However, much to my disappointment, my attempt at the renderer code(pasted below) results in a weird half-way-there  VR view.  The stereoscopic view is rendered with the desired distortion on each eye however the underlying frame images are not in duplicated for each eye -instead it the full screen single image is rendered with the the eye portals sitting over the top!  Also the frames are rendered in grayscale!  If anyone has got this to work properly I would really appreciate some help :)

Here is the code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.EyeTransform;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.HeadTransform;
import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.Viewport;
import com.opentok.android.BaseVideoRenderer;

public class CustomVideoStereoRendererWorking extends BaseVideoRenderer {

    Context mContext;

    CardboardView mView;

    MyRenderer mRenderer;

    static class MyRenderer implements CardboardView.StereoRenderer {

        int mTextureIds[] = new int[3];
        float[] mScaleMatrix = new float[16];

        private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
        private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;
        private ShortBuffer mDrawListBuffer;

        boolean mVideoFitEnabled = true;
        boolean mVideoDisabled = false;

        // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
        static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
        static final int TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;

        static float mXYZCoords[] = { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top left
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
                1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f // top right
        };

        static float mUVCoords[] = { 0, 0, // top left
                0, 1, // bottom left
                1, 1, // bottom right
                1, 0 }; // top right

        private short mVertexIndex[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw
                                                                // vertices

        private final String vertexShaderCode = 
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" + 
                //"attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" + 
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" + 
                "void main() {\n" +
                //"  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" + 
                "  gl_Position = vec4 ( aPosition.x, aPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 );\n" + //from working renderer
                "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" + 
                "}\n";

        /*"attribute vec2 vPosition;\n" + 
         * "attribute vec2 vTexCoord;\n" +
         * "varying vec2 texCoord;\n" + 
         * "void main() {\n" + 
         * "  texCoord = vTexCoord;\n" +
         * "  gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 );\n" + 
         * "}";*/


        private final String fragmentShaderCode = 
                "precision mediump float;\n" + 
                "uniform sampler2D Ytex;\n" + 
                "uniform sampler2D Utex,Vtex;\n" + 
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" + 
                "void main(void) {\n" +
                "  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;\n" + 
                "  mediump vec4 txl,ux,vx;" + 
                "  nx=vTextureCoord[0];\n" + 
                "  ny=vTextureCoord[1];\n" +
                "  y=texture2D(Ytex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" + 
                "  u=texture2D(Utex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" + 
                "  v=texture2D(Vtex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" +
                //"  y=1.0-1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" + // Invert effect
                //"  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" + // Normal renderer
                "  u=u-0.5;\n" + 
                "  v=v-0.5;\n" + 
                "  r=y+1.5958*v;\n" + 
                "  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;\n" + 
                "  b=y+2.017*u;\n" + 
                "  gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);\n" + 
                "}\n";

        /*
        private final String fragmentShaderCode = 
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" + 
                "uniform samplerExternalOES Ytex;\n" + 
                "uniform samplerExternalOES Utex,Vtex;\n" + 
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" + 
                "void main(void) {\n" +
                "  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;\n" + 
                "  mediump vec4 txl,ux,vx;" + 
                "  nx=vTextureCoord[0];\n" + 
                "  ny=vTextureCoord[1];\n" +
                "  y=texture2D(Ytex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" + 
                "  u=texture2D(Utex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" + 
                "  v=texture2D(Vtex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n" +
                //"  y=1.0-1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" + // Invert effect
                //"  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n" + // Normal renderer
                "  u=u-0.5;\n" + 
                "  v=v-0.5;\n" + 
                "  r=y+1.5958*v;\n" + 
                "  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;\n" + 
                "  b=y+2.017*u;\n" + 
                "  gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);\n" + 
                "}\n";
        */

        /*"#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" + 
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
        "varying vec2 texCoord;\n" + 
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture,texCoord);\n" + 
        "}"*/


        ReentrantLock mFrameLock = new ReentrantLock();
        Frame mCurrentFrame;

        private int mProgram;
        private int mTextureWidth;
        private int mTextureHeight;
        private int mViewportWidth;
        private int mViewportHeight;

        public MyRenderer() {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mXYZCoords.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mVertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            mVertexBuffer.put(mXYZCoords);
            mVertexBuffer.position(0);

            ByteBuffer tb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mUVCoords.length * 4);
            tb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mTextureBuffer = tb.asFloatBuffer();
            mTextureBuffer.put(mUVCoords);
            mTextureBuffer.position(0);

            ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertexIndex.length * 2);
            dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mDrawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
            mDrawListBuffer.put(mVertexIndex);
            mDrawListBuffer.position(0);
        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig config) {
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
            int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

            mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram(); // create empty OpenGL ES
                                                    // Program
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); // add the vertex
                                                            // shader to program
            GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment
                                                                // shader to
                                                                // program
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

            int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            int textureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4, mVertexBuffer);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TEXTURECOORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4,
                    mTextureBuffer);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureHandle);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            int i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Ytex");
            GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 0); /* Bind Ytex to texture unit 0 */

            i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Utex");
            GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 1); /* Bind Utex to texture unit 1 */

            i = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Vtex");
            GLES20.glUniform1i(i, 2); /* Bind Vtex to texture unit 2 */

            mTextureWidth = 0;
            mTextureHeight = 0;
        }

        static void initializeTexture(int name, int id, int width, int height) {
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(name);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, id);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
        }

        void setupTextures(Frame frame) {
            if (mTextureIds[0] != 0) {
                GLES20.glDeleteTextures(3, mTextureIds, 0);
            }
            GLES20.glGenTextures(3, mTextureIds, 0);

            int w = frame.getWidth();
            int h = frame.getHeight();
            int hw = (w + 1) >> 1;
            int hh = (h + 1) >> 1;

            initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, mTextureIds[0], w, h);
            initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1, mTextureIds[1], hw, hh);
            initializeTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2, mTextureIds[2], hw, hh);

            mTextureWidth = frame.getWidth();
            mTextureHeight = frame.getHeight();
        }

        void updateTextures(Frame frame) {
            int width = frame.getWidth();
            int height = frame.getHeight();
            int half_width = (width + 1) >> 1;
            int half_height = (height + 1) >> 1;
            int y_size = width * height;
            int uv_size = half_width * half_height;

            ByteBuffer bb = frame.getBuffer();
            // If we are reusing this frame, make sure we reset position and
            // limit
            bb.clear();

            if (bb.remaining() == y_size + uv_size * 2) {
                bb.position(0);

                GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[0]);
                GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

                bb.position(y_size);
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[1]);
                GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, half_width, half_height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

                bb.position(y_size + uv_size);
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[2]);
                GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, half_width, half_height, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
            } else {
                mTextureWidth = 0;
                mTextureHeight = 0;
            }

        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            mViewportWidth = width;
            mViewportHeight = height;
        }

        public void onDrawEye(EyeTransform arg0) {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            mFrameLock.lock();
            if (mCurrentFrame != null && !mVideoDisabled) {
                GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

                if (mTextureWidth != mCurrentFrame.getWidth() || mTextureHeight != mCurrentFrame.getHeight()) {
                    setupTextures(mCurrentFrame);
                }
                updateTextures(mCurrentFrame);

                Matrix.setIdentityM(mScaleMatrix, 0);
                float scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f;
                float ratio = (float) mCurrentFrame.getWidth() / mCurrentFrame.getHeight();
                float vratio = (float) mViewportWidth / mViewportHeight;

                if (mVideoFitEnabled) {
                    if (ratio > vratio) {
                        scaleY = vratio / ratio;
                    } else {
                        scaleX = ratio / vratio;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ratio < vratio) {
                        scaleY = vratio / ratio;
                    } else {
                        scaleX = ratio / vratio;
                    }
                }

                Matrix.scaleM(mScaleMatrix, 0, scaleX * (mCurrentFrame.isMirroredX() ? -1.0f : 1.0f), scaleY, 1);

                int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mScaleMatrix, 0);

                GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mVertexIndex.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mDrawListBuffer);
            }
            mFrameLock.unlock();

        }

        public void displayFrame(Frame frame) {
            mFrameLock.lock();
            if (this.mCurrentFrame != null) {
                this.mCurrentFrame.recycle();
            }
            this.mCurrentFrame = frame;
            mFrameLock.unlock();
        }

        public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e("Shader", "Could not compile vshader");
                Log.v("Shader", "Could not compile vshader:" + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }

            return shader;
        }

        public void disableVideo(boolean b) {
            mFrameLock.lock();

            mVideoDisabled = b;

            if (mVideoDisabled) {
                if (this.mCurrentFrame != null) {
                    this.mCurrentFrame.recycle();
                }
                this.mCurrentFrame = null;
            }

            mFrameLock.unlock();
        }

        public void enableVideoFit(boolean enableVideoFit) {
            mVideoFitEnabled = enableVideoFit;
        }

        public void onFinishFrame(Viewport arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onRendererShutdown() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    public CustomVideoStereoRendererWorking(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

        mView = new CardboardView(context);
        mView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mView.setVRModeEnabled(true);

        mRenderer = new MyRenderer();
        mView.setRenderer(mRenderer);

        mView.setRenderMode(CardboardView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrame(Frame frame) {
        mRenderer.displayFrame(frame);
        mView.requestRender();
    }

    @Override
    public void setStyle(String key, String value) {
        if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_SCALE.equals(key)) {
            if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FIT.equals(value)) {
                mRenderer.enableVideoFit(true);
            } else if (BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FILL.equals(value)) {
                mRenderer.enableVideoFit(false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoPropertiesChanged(boolean videoEnabled) {
        mRenderer.disableVideo(!videoEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mView.onResume();
    }

}
```